# Combine multiple perl scripts, commands in an executable script in linux

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I have created a few perl scripts, which i run one after the other:

```
perl script_one.pl file.txt

perl script_two.pl

perl script_three.pl
```

command file_one.log file_two.log

a perl one liner

for example

```
perl -lpe 's/\s*$//'
```

How could i combine all the above in a bash script?

i work on an ubuntu 16.04 machine

I have tried with the && in linux, but i got errors

Comment: How did you try with `&&`? And which errors did you get?

Comment: i am looking at a way to implement this with a bash script, and not &&

Comment: Bash executes script's commands one by one. So you can write this commands in file and run it.

Comment: Your code block in the question already is a valid bash script. Just put one command per line and you're good.

Comment: why should you not try the *BAT file

Comment: an example with the BAT file?

Comment: @Marios: `&&` ***is bash syntax*** and will work fine in a bash script. Please tell us what happened when you tried to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Create file(for example `script.sh`) with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
perl script_one.pl file.txt
perl script_two.pl
perl script_three.pl
```

And then execute `chmod +x script.sh` and `./script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I would normally define the scripts with the shebang: #!/bin/bash
Generally, #!/bin/sh is the same thing as #!/bin/bash in the terminal
but there can be some differences in advanced programs.
Save the script as file.bash, for example 
Then you execute the script with: 
$ bash file.bash

And it runs like it would in the terminal.

#

But if you have multiple perl programs, you can make them all null subroutines (functions) in a large perl script and then execute the subroutines one after another. See how I have 3 scripts which I made into null subroutines with just this logic:

sub this { # Your code goes here } # Assuming this is your function.

Execute your script with: "this()",
and it does whatever this() does.

So imagine that these basic null subroutines in this perl script,
are separate perl scripts. In one script like this one I run all those perl scripts like so ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# multiple_programs.pl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# A subroutine can be a whole perl script.
# Just write sub function { # all your code in a script }.
# Then execute your subroutine with function() ... if your subroutine is called function, for example. 
# If you want to execute multiple scripts subroutines with no external data passed into them can be quite nifty!
# If you define your variables within the subroutine and don't pass anything to them. 
# Notice how in this logical workflow I have defined no variables outside of the subroutines. 
# This can make your life easier sometimes. 

# Now we execute the null subroutines (functions) one after another like so. 
sum(); # Imagine this is the first script: sum.pl
too_friendly(); # Imagine this is the second script: too_friendly.pl
open_file(); # Imagine that this is the third script called open_file.pl

sub sum 
{
my $i = 1;
print "Input the maximum value that you would like to sum numbers up to from 1: >>";
my $max = <STDIN>;
my $sum;

while($i <= $max)
{
    $sum += $i;
    $i++;
}
print "The sum of The numbers 1 to $max is $sum\n";
}

sub too_friendly
{ # Put brackets around your whole code. 
say "\nWhat's your name?";
my $name = <STDIN>;
say "Hey buddy! Long time no see, $name!";
say "What's up!?";
}

sub open_file
{
say "\nI will open a file for you, and read the contents of it";
print "Okay, which file? >>";
chomp(my $file = <STDIN>); # The actual filename.
my $filehandle; # A temporary variable to a file.

unless(open($filehandle, '<', $file)){die "Could not open file $file";}

while(my $rows = <$filehandle>)
    {
    print "$rows";
    }
    close $filehandle;
}
```

My perl script does three things for the three subroutines.
It calculates the sum of numbers 1 to n, with "n" provided by the user.
It is way too friendly, and it opens a file and just straight up reads it line by line.

For example, here is how it works: 
This is not code. It's example output from running the above perl program:

```
Input the maximum value that you would like to sum numbers up to from 1: >>15
The sum of The numbers 1 to 15
 is 120

What's your name?
Brother
Hey buddy! Long time no see, Brother
!
What's up!?

I will open a file for you, and read the contents of it
Okay, which file? >>A_file.txt
Hey,
What's happening?
I am just file in your working directory,
and you just opened me.
Pretty cool, huh!?
Okay, bye!
```

Comment: The advantage of making a script like this is that you can have one perl script that does the work of 3 perl scripts, instead of making 3 separate perl scripts plus a bash script.